# How to get full width dropdown area with a container of all menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please help me to do menu:

[image: like this]

I found a link like that

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/6cu8f43m/`
```

but it doesn't get full width navbar with a container menu items

Comment: Please add what you have tried till now.

Comment: Please used the [edit] button and add your code to the question, rather than add a link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In that code also mentioned that details for full-width sub-menu items.

choose the full-width in all the li items. like below:

```
 <li class="dropdown full-width">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Fill Width <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                        </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**JFiddle Demo** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3awp1z0r/)

**snippet Example Below**

```css
.full-width.dropdown {
    position: static;
}
.full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
   white-space: normal; 
}


.fill-width.dropdown {
    position: static;
}
.fill-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.fill-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
   white-space: normal; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown full-width">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Normal <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                            </a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li class="dropdown full-width">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Full Width <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                            </a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>          
                <li class="dropdown full-width">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Fill Width <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                            </a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0; background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
    About this SO Question:
    <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/q/26147186/1366033'>
        How To Restrict Width of Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Menu
    </a><br/>
    Fork This Skeleton Here: 
    <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>
        Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
    </a><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the class of outermost div to navbar instead of container. 
Or better just use `<nav> </nav>` instead of outermost `<div class="container"> </div>`